# BibTeX does not work

Tags: bibtex

Hey I am completely lost. Despite me going to several websites and copying their commands directly, my LaTeX document refuses to generate either the citation or bibliography entry. Here is the LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{qtree}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{cite}

\geometry{a4paper}

\title{Nominals of Modern Greek (Abstract)}

\author{Dingler, Ian}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Important to note, is that if their are no other items in the lexical phrase, the D must appear to the left side of N i.e. *\textit{podia ta}, \citet{MG21}.

\bibliographystyle{te}

\bibliography{Syn3 Ref}

\end{document}
```

Here is my bib entry saved as "Syn3 Ref"

```
@book{MG21,

       auTHor = {Brian D. Joseph and Irene Philippaki-Warburton},

       YEAR = {1987},

       Title = {Modern Greek},

       publisher = {Biddles Ltd, Guilford and Kin'gs Lynn},

       address = {Great Britain}
     }
```

Both my `.tex` and `.bib` files are saved in the same folder yet all I get when I typeset is a `?` where my citation should be and no bibliography entry what so ever.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the bibliography, you need to run BibTeX. Example for a calling sequence:

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

The BibTeX run will fail because of two problems:

```
$ bibtex test
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I couldn't open style file te.bst
---line 3 of file test.aux
 : \bibstyle{te
 :             }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 4 of file test.aux
 : \bibdata{Syn3
 :               Ref}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file test.aux
I found no style file---while reading file test.aux
(There were 4 error messages)
```

1. The bibliography style `te` is not known (at least in my system `te.bst` is missing). The example below uses one of the many bibliography styles, replace
   it to your needs.
2. BibTeX does not like spaces in the file name for the `.bib` file. For example, rename `Syn3 Ref.bib` to `Syn3Ref.bib`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage{cite}  
\geometry{a4paper}

\title{Nominals of Modern Greek (Abstract)}
\author{Dingler, Ian}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Important to note, is that if their are no other items in the lexical
phrase, the D must appear to the left side of N i.e. *\textit{podia ta},
\citet{MG21}.

\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliography{Syn3Ref}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Something must still be wrong. I tried running your text in a separate window and it still gave me the same output. Is it an issue with me not running BibTex?

Comment: One shouldn't load both `cite` and `natbib`.

Comment: @IanDingler Have you renamed the `.bib` file without spaces in the file name (also the file name needs to be changed in the `.tex` file accordingly)? Have you run the *whole* sequence given in the answer (`pdflatex` and `bibtex` runs)? Do you get error messages? Which ones?

Comment: Yes I tried removing the spaces from the .bib and .tex file as well as the cite package. I copied and pasted the answer into its own window and still get the same output. I do not get any error messages when I try typsetting though. What do you mean by "run bibtex"? Should I be using the calling sequence in the answer to do some kind of test? I have a separate program BibDesk in which I have also made an entry. Should this help?

Comment: @IanDingler The answer assumes, the TeX file is called `test.tex`. Then in a command window (koncole, dos prompt, ...) the commands `pdflatex test`, `bibtex test`, `pdflatex test`, and `pdflatex test` need to be executed.

Comment: When I try and run pdflatex test it says "I can't find file pdflatex". All other commands yeild a similar answer.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. Thank you all for your assistance.