# Bibtex wont work

Tags: bibtex

Please help! I am completely at a loss. Despite me copying commands directly from websites, my Latex document refuses to typeset either my citation or bibliography entry. Below is my tex...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{qtree}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{cite}

\geometry{a4paper} 

\title{Nominals of Modern Greek (Abstract)}



\begin{document}

Important to note, is that if their are no other items in the lexical phrase, 
the D must appear to the left side of N i.e. *\textit{podia ta}, citet{MG21}.

\bibliographystyle{te}

\bibliography{Syn3 Ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

Here is my bibliography entry saved under "Syn3 Ref..."

```
 @book{MG21,

   auTHor = {Brian D. Joseph and Irene Philippaki-Warburton},

   YEAR = {1987},

   Title = {Modern Greek},

   publisher = {Biddles Ltd, Guilford and Kin'gs Lynn},

   address = {Great Britain}
 }
```

Comment: I would not put spaces in filenames. have you run bibtex? did it give any error messages.

Comment: It looks like you're loading both `cite` and `natbib`. Load one or the other citation management package, but not both. Since you use the macro `\citet`, I suggest you load `natbib`.

Comment: your `\cite` command is also missing a `\ `

Comment: You already asked this question a few minutes ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/bibtex-does-not-work

Comment: Ya I realize that. When I asked the question the first time I didn't see it on my profile so I asked again.

Comment: The \- was in the original document I just goofed and did not type it.

Comment: I tried deleting the cite package as well as deleting the space in the file name and it still gives me the same output.